# Sort a dictionary by its values' values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I currently have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "Chile": {
        "num_of_unique_ips": 1,
        "num_of_unique_asns": 1,
        "asns": {
            "AS16629 CTC. CORP S.A. (TELEFONICA EMPRESAS)": 1
        }
    },
    "China": {
        "num_of_unique_ips": 1,
        "num_of_unique_asns": 1,
        "asns": {
            "AS4808 China Unicom Beijing Province Network": 1
        }
    }, # this goes on and on for ever country
}
```

I converted it to a dictionary by running:

```
import json
login_by_country = json.loads(open('login_by_country.json', 'r'))
```

How would i go about sorting this dictionary by each country's `num_of_unique_ips` value?

Comment: 1. That JSON is broken. 2. Dictionaries and JSON objects aren't ordered data structures, what do you mean by *"sorting"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is only a part of that json file, the full file is too big to post here. i need to sort the ***dictionary*** i got from `json.load`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe dictionaries are ordered by insertion on CPython 3.6 and this is officially a language requirement starting with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sorted(login_by_country.items(), key=lambda it: it[1]['num_of_unique_ips'])
```

This will return a list of (country, values_dict) pairs. You can convert it back to a dictionary while keeping the sorted order by passing it to `OrderedDict`, or the regular `dict` if you're using a version of Python which guarantees dict ordering (cpython 3.6+ or pypy 2.5).

Answer (score 0):

As @johrsharpe said in comment - dictionary doesn't have to keep order (but probably they will keep in in newest Python).

You can create list with pairs `(num_of_unique_ips , country)` and then you can easily sort it and keep in order.

```
logins_by_country = {
    "Chile": {
        "num_of_unique_ips": 1,
        "num_of_unique_asns": 1,
        "asns": {
            "AS16629 CTC. CORP S.A. (TELEFONICA EMPRESAS)": 1
        }
    },
    "China": {
        "num_of_unique_ips": 1,
        "num_of_unique_asns": 1,
        "asns": {
            "AS4808 China Unicom Beijing Province Network": 1
        }
    }, # thi
}

data = [(val["num_of_unique_ips"], key) for key, val in logins_by_country.items()]

order = sorted(data) 

print(order)
```

Result. It sorts by `num_of_unique_ips` and `country` (if they have the sam `num_of_unique_ips`)

```
[(1, 'Chile'), (1, 'China')]
```

and now you can use it to get data from dictionary in expected order.

```
for number, country in order:
    print(logins_by_country[country])
```

You can also use it to create `OrderedDict` which will keep order

```
from collections import OrderedDict

new_dict = OrderedDict()

for number, country in order:
    new_dict[country] = logins_by_country[country]

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: how would i do this but still keep the dictionary i got from `json.load`?

Comment: you still have original dictionary - you have to only use list to get data from dictionary in correct order - see new code in answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "probably they will keep order in in newest Python"? Dictionaries are [guaranteed to keep order](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) in the newest (3.7) Python.

Comment: I know it - I only never remeber it was added in 3.6 or 3.7 and for some people even 3.6 is the future if they use 3.5 or 2.7.